# Origine di 'da quattro soldi'

Tags: idioms, etymology

Sapreste dire quale sia l'origine di 'da quattro soldi'; per esempio, '*un ristorante* da quattro soldi'.

Quali sarebbero gli evocati 'soldi' lì, e perché proprio quattro e non due, per esempio?

Se, come penso, l'origine è legata alla valuta corrente nel Regno d'Italia, cosa si comprava allora con quattro soldi?

Comment: Non è raro nemmeno *da due soldi*. E c'è la famosa *Opera da tre soldi*. Da noi si dice comunemente *da do schei*, ma anche *sinque schei* è un modo di indicare una somma trascurabile.

Comment: @egreg, l'opera da tre soldi (la _Dreigroschenoper_ di Brecht) non conta, perché è tedesca (anche se il significato dei tre Groschen è sempre quello)

Answer (score 4):

È già stato scritto che il soldo (il *solidus* latino, lo *shelling* inglese prima del passaggio alla sterlina centesimale) valeva cinque centesimi, cioè un ventesimo di lira; quindi anche tra le due guerre non è che si potesse comprare molto.

Però secondo me il "quattro" è usato nel senso di "poco", proprio come in "facciamo quattro passi" oppure "eravamo quattro gatti".

Answer (score 3):

In italiano si può dire sia "da quattro soldi" che da "due soldi" (oppure "da pochi soldi"), anche se il primo modo di dire è forse quello più diffuso.

Come hai giustamente dedotto, l'origine di questo modo di dire è collegato alla moneta che si usava un tempo. Dall'enciclopedia online Treccani alla voce "soldo" leggiamo:

> Con riferimento allo scarso valore che ha avuto il soldo nelle varie epoche, hanno avuto origine le espressioni comuni: ***roba da pochi soldi***, ***che non vale un soldo***, ***di poco o nessun valore;*** [...] Frequente anche l’espressione ***quattro soldi***, poco denaro, in alcune frasi tipiche: si dà tante arie per quei quattro s. che ha; crede di avermi comperato, per quei quattro s. che mi passa ogni mese; ha speso quei quattro s. che aveva da parte,; anche fig., nella locuz. ***da quattro soldi***, usata in funzione attributiva: ***un poeta da quattro soldi, che non vale nulla.***

Puoi leggere l'articolo completo qui: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/soldo/

Spero di esserti stata d'aiuto.

Comment: Non trovo che questa risposta aggiunga qualcosa a quello che già veniva detto nella domanda...

Comment: @DaG non aggiunge molto, però aggiunge un link alla Treccani dove si dice esplicitamente che si può dire sia "un soldo" sia "quattro soldi" che "pochi soldi", con riferimento «allo scarso valore che ha avuto il soldo nelle varie epoche».

Answer (score 3):

Altre lingue derivate dal latino hanno espressioni con il numero "quattro" nel senso di "poco":

- Francese: "à quatre pas d'ici", "pour quatre jours qu'on a à vivre".
- Catalano: "quatre rals" (con lo stesso significato che "quattro soldi"), "quate gats" (con lo stesso significato che "quattro gatti"), "és a quatre passes" (= è molto vicino), "quatre gotes" (pioggia molto debole o scarsa).

Ho anche letto che, durante il regno di Isabella II di Borbone, quando la peseta viene instaurata come moneta, questa si fece equivalere a "quatre rals".  Con questo voglio dire che, in catalano, molto probabilmente la gente abbia usato l'espressione "quatre rals" per riferirsi a una peseta.

@egreg: La traduzione al catalano di *Dreigroschenoper* è proprio *L'Òpera dels quatre rals* perché anche in catalano abbiamo l'espressione "quatre rals" (e non "tres rals") con lo stesso significato che l'espressione italiano "quattro soldi". 
[Scusate, ma non ho ancora il permesso di scrivere commenti.]

Answer (score 0):

Non riesco a commentare sotto le risposte di DaG e randomatlabuser perché non me lo permette. Aggiungo un commento qui sperando che si possa fare.

Alla domanda "perché proprio quattro e non due, per esempio?" non ho risposto perché non credo esista una risposta certa. E' un modo di dire che si è fissato nel tempo e non so se sia possibile risalire all'etimologia esatta. Né tantomeno è possibile conoscere alla perfezione cosa si potesse comprare con quattro e con due soldi.

In italiano esistono molte frasi idiomatiche con i soldi. Alcuni di queste sono:

> **mancare diciannove soldi a una lira**. Essere del tutto insufficiente.
>      (La lira era un tempo divisa in venti soldi).
>
> **non valere un soldo bucato**. Non valere nulla, nemmeno un soldo e per di più bucato.

fonte: http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/S/soldo.shtml

Dato che un soldo era 1/20 di lira, non escludo che "quattro soldi" e "due soldi" fossero cifre arbitrarie (che poi appunto si sono fissate nella lingua) utilizzate col significato di "poco valore".

Quanto a ciò che si poteva comprare con un soldo, la questione è complessa. Prima dell'Unità d'Italia ogni stato aveva le sue monete e i suoi prezzi, non c'erano prezzi comuni per tutti. Grano e una minestra sicuramente. Quattro soldi poteva anche essere lo stipendio minimo di un lavoratore, ma come ho detto dipende dai casi e non sono sicura che sia questa l'etimologia corretta.

Comment: Non ho riferimenti precisi, ma secondo me il "soldo bucato" non è inteso nell'accezione "rovinato". Sono esistite in passato delle monete di forma effettivamente bucata (credo che uno degli scopi fosse quello di poterli tenere insieme con uno spago, in maniera che non si perdessero). Evidentemente erano anche monete di poco valore.