# Il numero quattro come metafora

Tags: word-usage

Ci sono molti modi di dire in italiano dove il numero 4 viene usato in senso figurato.

Alcuni esempi sono:

- Fare quattro passi
- Dirne quattro
- Quattro gatti
- Fare il diavolo a quattro
- Gridare ai quattro venti
- Fare quattro salti
- Farsi in quattro,    etc.

In tutti i suddetti i modi di dire come in altri non elencati il numero quattro viene sempre usato per indicare un numero indefinito di cose o persone, come se il numero quattro avesse anche una connotazione di numero generico, indefinito.

Qualcuno sa perché il 4 viene usato con la connotazione spiegata sopra?  Ha per caso a che fare con qualche scienza occulta o con qualche vecchia credenza?

Comment: Domanda correlata: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1722/origine-di-da-quattro-soldi.

Comment: Per ora non ho una risposta, ma una possibile indicazione bibliografica. È possibile che in Carla Bazzanella, _Numeri per parlare. Da ‘quattro chiacchiere’ a ‘grazie mille’_ (Laterza 2011), che non ho letto, ci sia qualcosa di utile.

Comment: In “gridare ai quattro venti” non vedo un uso di “quattro” come numero indefinito. Nemmeno molto in “farsi in quattro”.

Comment: Quattro e due (secondo la _Tre_ ccani `:-)` ) sono usati per indicare un valore indeterminato, pochi, poche... temo non ci sia una risposta univoca.  Prendendo spunto da Wikipedia _"4, nel Medioevo è considerato un numero perno e risolutore: quattro sono, infatti, i punti cardinali, i venti principali, le stagioni, le fasi lunari, le arti liberali del quadrivio, i lati del quadrato a cui veniva paragonata la Terra (in opposizione al triangolo del cielo, simbolo della Trinità). Inoltre quattro è il numero della perfezione morale e delle proporzioni dell'uomo."_ e nel ME è nato l'Italiano...